# What is the purpose of compare(key, key) in Java TreeMap put() method when root == null?

Tags: java

I am reading Java 1.8 TreeMap source code.
The put method is written as below:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> t = root;
    if (t == null) {
        compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check

        root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
        size = 1;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
...... //more code
}
```

When root == null, which means that it is the first time for us to put an Entry, why we still need to compare the key itself before we assign the entry to root?

BTW, compare method is :

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator==null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the source please.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava what I paste is the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment explains why:

```
// type (and possibly null) check
```

This `compare` will ensure that `key` is not `null`, and has the expected type, before it is stored in the map.

In the `compare` method, as shown, the `key` is either cast to a `Comparable`, and has `compareTo` invoked, or it is passed as an argument to the `comparator`. These operations will fail with either `NullPointerException`s or `ClassCastExceptions` if `key` is `null`, or not of the required type for the `comparator` to handle.

Comment: but the compare method seems not do the type and null check (refer to my code)

Comment: @LeonloveKaren It does both, just not explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The comment hints at what is going on.

```
// type (and possibly null) check
```

A correctly implemented `Comparator` or `Comparable` will check that its arguments have types that it understands before comparing them.  It *may* also test if the arguments are not `null` ... depending on whether it implements an ordering where `null` is or isn't allowed.

By using `compare` to compare the initial key to itself, the code is checking that key has an appropriate type, and *optionally* that it is not `null`.

---

You commented:

> but the compare method seems not do the type and null check

This is the code you are talking about.

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator==null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

The checks we are talking about happen as follows.

- When `comparator` is `null`:

  - An *implicit* `null` check on `k1` occurs when `k1.compareTo(k2)` is called.
  - A type check occurs in the `(Comparable)` cast to ensure that `k1` is a `Comparable`.
  - A second type check will typically happen within the key's `compareTo` method.
- When `comparator` is not `null`, the type check and the (optional in this case) `null` check happen within the `Comparator<K>.compare` method that we are calling.

(The casts to `(K)` are unchecked type casts and won't do any actual type checking.)

Comment: `new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>()` does not accept null keys, but `new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))` does.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  In the latter case, 1) there is a comparator, and 2) the comparator accepts `null` as a value.  (There will be an explicit a null check happening in the `nullsFirst` comparator, but the check doesn't lead to an NPE.)